# Simply creating a RenderTargetBitmap in App.OnStartup causes memory (only when MainWindow is created too). What is it causing?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, windows-7

I scavenged various SO threads, MSDN and also this bug report on [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/648683/memory-leak-in-wpf-of-dispatcher-and-mediacontext-objects-resulting-in-win32exceptions) but I do not understand, what actually causes the memory leak in the following trivial WPF project (this is a repro, just create any new WPF project and put this into `App.xaml.cs`

```
    protected override void OnStartup( StartupEventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnStartup( e );

        new MainWindow();

        for ( var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i )
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(2000, 2000, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            Thread.Sleep( 100 );
        }


    }
```

Even with occasional GCs there is a constant increase in memory:
[image: Memory build up]

Now RenderTargetBitmap does not implement IDisposable and I tried various things like getting the Dispatcher of the MainWindow etc.

However, when I comment out the `new MainWindow()` line, I no longer get the memory build up. I also tried moving the code into the `Loaded` Event of the original StartupUri window (hence not calling `new MainWindow()` by myself), same effect.

Where does this RenderTargetBitmap memory build actually comes from?

Environment:

- Windows 7 x64 (Windows 10 does not show this effect)
- Visual Studio 2017
- Debug | x64
- .net Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Same environment, I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtbVx.png

Comment: @ThomasWeller can you zip the entire project and provide it by some means? Meanwhile I executed the exe on a windows 10 and it does not show any leak.

Comment: @ThomasWeller your sample is leaking. Can you check, whether your machine has this KB https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/967634/fix-you-may-experience-several-issues-when-you-render-graphics-by-usin which contains these KB: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2667241 . Can you find out your presentationcore date, version and size?

Comment: @ThomasWeller you'll find it under C:\Windows\assembly (which shows a special view), go to PresentationCore and right click the x64 version (be aware the dialog might appear on the wrong window), my version is 3.0.6920.8773

Comment: Same version here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNfTZ.png

Comment: @ThomasWeller really really really WTF. I hope somebody else can reproduce this. I've tested my binary on several Win 7 machines with various levels of patches and they all exhibit the leak pattern. Many thanks for your effort!